# compare two query results in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to write a script to compare data from two databases.

In particular, trying to generate output to list match/unmatch sequences for ecah client.

There are two databases

AORCL database

```
SQL> select * from ffduser.client_mapping;
  CLIENTNO  CLIENTSEQ STATUS
---------- ---------- ----------
         1       1000 VALID
         2       2000 VALID
```

BORCL database

```
SQL> select * from ffduser.client_mapping;
  CLIENTNO  CLIENTSEQ STATUS
---------- ---------- ----------
         1       1000 VALID
         2       2002 VALID
```

Expected output

```
Clientno 1 has Clientseq 1000 in AORCL and 1000 in BORCL -> Match
Clientno 2 has Clientseq 2000 in AORCL and 2001 in BORCL -> UnMatch
```

==========

I wrote below code but not able to generate expected output. 
I think it may require nested loop but I am novice. 
Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/pytho
import cx_Oracle
pdb_name = 'AORCL'
ddb_name = 'BORCL'
pserver_name = 'ff1db03'
dserver_name = 'ff1db03'
pcon = cx_Oracle.connect('system/xxxxx@'+pserver_name+':1521/'+pdb_name)
dcon = cx_Oracle.connect('system/xxxxx@'+dserver_name+':1521/'+ddb_name)
pcur = pcon.cursor()
dcur = dcon.cursor()
pstat = pcur.execute('select clientno,clientseq from ffduser.client_mapping order by clientno').fetchall()

for plogresult in pstat:
    print (pdb_name +'->'+ ' Client# '+str(plogresult[0])+' Seq No# ' +str(plogresult[1]))

dstat = dcur.execute("select clientno,clientseq from ffduser.client_mapping where status='VALID' order by clientno").fetchall()
for dlogresult in dstat:
        print (pdb_name +'->'+' Client# '+str(dlogresult[0])+' Seq No# ' +str(dlogresult[1]))

pcur.close()
pcon.close()
dcur.close()
dcon.close()


$ python test.py
AORCL-> Client# 1 Seq No# 1000
AORCL-> Client# 2 Seq No# 2000
AORCL-> Client# 1 Seq No# 1000
AORCL-> Client# 2 Seq No# 2002
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Take a [tour]. Read [ask]. Create a [mcve].

Comment: Why don't you do a join on name?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need one method which I would call `select_to_name_value_mapping(table_name)`

This method returns a dictionary with the "names" as keys and the Eno as values.

```
mapping1=select_to_name_value_mapping('table1')
mapping2=select_to_name_value_mapping('table2')

for key1, value1 in mapping1.items():
    value2=mapping2.get(key1)
    print('key=%s table1=%s table2=%s' % (key1, value1, value2))

print('missing in mapping1: %s' % set(mapping1.keys())-set(mapping2.keys()))
```

The implementation of `select_to_name_value_mapping(table_name)` is up to you :-)

Above is the implementation in Python. It is easier for human brains to find this iterative approach. You can et the same result with SQL, but it is harder to get the "thinking in sets" solution. My advice: learn thinking in sets.

Comment: Your approach has a two problems: If a key is in mapping1, but not in mapping2, you output `None` and  include it as `missing in mapping1` entry. If a key is in mapping2, but not in mapping1, it will never get printed.

Comment: @CodingLambdas I know that my solution is not perfect. It was a hint how to solve this.