# How to get difference in flask SQLalchemy queries then order the queries

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am still trying to figure out queries. I was able to make two queries and now I am trying to figure out how to combine them. For the models.py I have a `class Ingredient(db.Model)`. In my views.py I have the queries:

```
i0 = db.session.query(Ingredient).filter(Ingredient.ROrder.isnot(None), 
     Ingredient.recipe_id==0).order_by(Ingredient.ROrder)
ir = db.session.query(Ingredient).filter(Ingredient.ROrder.isnot(None), 
     Ingredient.recipe_id==recipe_id).order_by(Ingredient.ROrder)
```

Okay so there is another column and I want to know the source_id.  If source_id is present in the ir then I don't want the instance of source_id in i0. I hope this makes sense.

---

Edit to add table image

The table is like so.

| source_id | name | Descriptor | tv | ROrder | recipe_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3110 | Baking Powder |  | 61 |  | 0 |
| C100 | Flour | All-purpose | 1781 | 362 | 0 |
| C100 | Flour | Bread | 1346 | 207 | 1 |
| 3120 | Baking Soda |  | 83 |  | 0 |
| B121 | Brown Sugar | Light | 542 | 41 | 1 |
| B121 | Brown Sugar | Dark | 97 | 18 | 0 |

All records have source_id and recipe_id.

Comment: why not using `if` and `else` condition statement?

Comment: @Rizquuula - Can you share an example?

Comment: check these examples. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56200605/5091720 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55879708/5091720 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42107091/5091720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combined = db.session.query(Ingredient).filter(Ingredient.ROrder.isnot(None)).\ 
    filter(_or(Ingredient.recipe_id==0, Ingredient.recipe_id==recipe_id)).\
    order_by(Ingredient.ROrder)
```

It sounds like you should be using a single query. If this is not the solution you seek, please farther explain the conditions you're trying to grab.

EDIT:
I didn't run this locally so I may have syntax error but I would likely do something like this. Just save all the data into a dictionary and when you get a source_id that already exist, overwrite the values if recipe_id==recipe_id.

```
combined_objects = db.session.query(Ingredient).filter(Ingredient.ROrder.isnot(None)).\ 
    filter(_or(Ingredient.recipe_id==0, Ingredient.recipe_id==recipe_id)).\
    order_by(Ingredient.ROrder).all()

data_dict = {}
source_id_list = []

for combined_object in combined_objects:
    if combined_object.source_id not in data_dict.keys():
        # add to dictionary
        temp_dict = {'name': combined_object.name, 'Descriptor': combined_object.Descriptor,
             'tv': combined_object.tv, 'ROrder': combined_object.ROrder, 'recipe_id': combined_object.recipe_id}
        data_dict[combined_object.source_id] = temp_dict
        # keep track of list of source_ids
        source_id_list.append(combined_object.source_id)
    
    # if key is already in dictionary, check if recipe_id==recipe_id, if it does, overwrite data in dictionary
    else:
        if combined_object.recipe_id == recipe_id:
            # add to dictionary
            temp_dict = {'name': combined_object.name, 'Descriptor': combined_object.Descriptor,
                'tv': combined_object.tv, 'ROrder': combined_object.ROrder, 'recipe_id': combined_object.recipe_id}
            data_dict[combined_object.source_id] = temp_dict

# show result
for source_id in source_id_list:
    print(data_dict[source_id])
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the single query. Sometimes, because of the data with the recipe_id I end up with 2 source_id values. I would prefer first `Ingredient.recipe_id==recipe_id` when there are 2. Is there a way to get `.first()` too? something like
`combined2 = combined(Ingredient.source_id).first()`

Comment: By the way, I learned to use **or_**  you need to import first `from sqlalchemy import or_`

Comment: Can you complete describe your entire model (table) for me?

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to query. I can easily write the query for you if I understand what it is you're wanting and if you show me entire table.

Comment: I like your confidence. I edited the question to add a table image.